# Setting print layout to portrait using QGIS 3?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-print-layouts

I can't get the print layout to appear in portrait.  It opens in landscape and Layout/Page Setup... allows for portrait, but the layout canvas remains in landscape.

In 2.18 the "Composition" Panel has "Page Size" as its first item, with a drop down Landscape/Portrait control box.

[image: 2.18 Page size]

In 3.0.0, the "Layout" Panel does not have this, and I can't find it in the "Item Properties" panel.

Is there somewhere that I can set it to portrait?

Comment: Adding some key words in the hope that search will pick them up:  page paper size orientation background hight width.   I missed this when searching on "paper  size"

Answer (score 98, accepted):

In QGIS 3.x you have to right click on the page in your layout to find "Page Properties".[image]

Comment: This is a rather hidden feature.

Comment: simple, but difficult to find! thank you @michel-stuyts for the answer.

Comment: Very hidden, is there any feature request (or even a bug!) open?

Comment: This is a major failure ('major' in context of layout design, not 'major' overall) of usability for QGIS 3. The issue is lack of 'discoverability' - even someone looking hard for this feature (like me) is unlikely to find it.

Comment: lmao big UI fail. thanks for the answer tho

Comment: Since QGIS 3.20 the properties are accessible by left-clicking in a page, they are then shown in the Item Properties tab in the panel on the side. https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/26237

Answer (score -3):

Ok this is usefull info, 
and something else considering atlasfeatures in Layout:

( in 2.18 i used a statement to determine landscape or portrait of a atlasfeature, using the bounds witdh and height) and 
in 2.18 statement was a $atlasgeometry
in 3.2 this should be @atlas_geometry 
although it is the same layer in wich this is working.

Comment: Your answer does not contribute to the question.